# Trouble with the data read from UR5 robot's TCP/IP port

Tags: matlab, robotics

I wrote the MATLAB code below to read some stream of data from the TCP/IP 30003 port of UR5.The kind of result I am getting which is different from what is on my Robot (I am using URSim 3.5.3 Virtual environment) but it supposes to be same. Although it looks close to it since there are 6 data as expected.

I believe this is possible because someone used python to achieve it http://www.zacobria.com/universal-robots-knowledge-base-tech-support-forum-hints-tips/knowledge-base/client-interfaces-cartesian-matlab-data/, but I am instructed to use MATLAB.

MATLAB CODE

```
clear all

HOST = '192.168.56.101';
PORT_30003 = 30003;

while (true)
s = tcpclient(HOST, PORT_30003);
disp('connected and starting program');
disp('data received:');

data = read(s, 80, 'double');

disp(data(56:61));

pause(1);
end
```

RESULT OBTAINED:

```
>> ur5
connected and starting program
data received:
1.0e-15 *

-0.4406    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000


connected and starting program
data received:
1.0e-15 *

-0.4406    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
```

Same continuously since the robot isn't moved but is so different from the values in my robot. The 1st line is for the Cartesian coordinates (X,Y,Z,RX,RY,RZ) but the values on my robot at the time of running the program were: -120.11mm, -431.76mm, 146.07mm, 0.0012, -3.1664, -0.0395 and the 2nd one is for Gripper state (X,Y,Z,RX,RY,RZ). Do anyone has idea whether it is a conversion problem? and how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

The Universal Robots Matlab interface (real time client / port 30003) sends a data of packet structure:

```
int LENGTH
double PAYLOAD_0
double PAYLOAD_1
double ...
double PAYLOAD_n
```

The length can vary by software version, so it is suggested to read the length first, and then read the remaining double values. If you do not read the complete length of the package, there might be some "remainders of the last package" in your input buffer, and then the next package you read will be nonsense.

Therefore I would recommend reading length, buffering remaining package, and then extracting the packages of interest.

```
length = read(s, 1, 'int64')
payload = read(s, length, 'double')
disp(payload(x:y))
```

You can find the official documentation of the [UR TCP interfaces here](https://www.universal-robots.com/how-tos-and-faqs/how-to/ur-how-tos/remote-control-via-tcpip-16496/).
Note that the port 30003 interface sometimes gets extended, with new variabls at the end. The complete length in doubles should be something like 139 doubles.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem as you.

We established a socket connection to the robot with a TCPclient. We wanted to get the positions of the axes from the robot. We did this with the read command and then converted it with typecast with the right byteorder.

The solution we found was.

**Matlab Code**

```
clear all
HOST = '192.168.56.101';
PORT_30003 = 30003;
s = tcpclient(HOST, PORT_30003);
disp('connected and starting program');
s.flush;
data = read(s, 1220, 'uint8');
disp('data received:');
% use flip to get the right bight order
% read the actual joint position
q_joint_1 = typecast(flip(data(253:260),'double');
% or typecast(uint8 ([data(260), data(259), data(258) ,data(257), data(256), data(255), data(254), data(253)]),'double');
disp(q_joint_1);
pause(1);
```